# error message, not working properly - prolog

Tags: prolog

How to repair a program to be ready to be used with SWI Prolog?

Link to source: http://ai-programming.com/prolog_bot_tutorial.htm
chatterbot2:

I modified `read_string` and `write_string` to `read` and `write`:

```
    knowledge_base([
    ['WHAT IS YOUR NAME', 
    ['MY NAME IS CHATTERBOT2.',
     'YOU CAN CALL ME CHATTERBOT2.',
     'WHY DO YOU WANT TO KNOW MY NAME?']
    ],

    ['HI', 
    ['HI THERE!',
     'HOW ARE YOU?',
     'HI!']
    ],

    ['HOW ARE YOU',
    ['I''M DOING FINE!',
    'I''M DOING WELL AND YOU?',
    'WHY DO YOU WANT TO KNOW HOW AM I DOING?']
    ],

    ['WHO ARE YOU',
    ['I''M AN A.I PROGRAM.',
     'I THINK THAT YOU KNOW WHO I''M.',
     'WHY ARE YOU ASKING?']
    ],

    ['ARE YOU INTELLIGENT',
    ['YES,OFCORSE.',
     'WHAT DO YOU THINK?',
     'ACTUALY,I''M VERY INTELLIGENT!']
    ],

    ['ARE YOU REAL',
    ['DOES THAT QUESTION REALLY MATERS TO YOU?',
     'WHAT DO YOU MEAN BY THAT?',
     'I''M AS REAL AS I CAN BE.']
     ] ]).

select(0, [H|_], H).
select(N, [_|T], L) :- N > 0, N1 is N - 1, select(N1, T, L).

list_length([], 0).
list_length([_|T], Length):- list_length(T, Length2), Length is Length2 + 1.

quit_session(X):- X = bye, 
    nl, write('IT WAS NICE TALKING TO YOU USER, SEE YOU NEXT TIME!').

no_response_found(ListOfResponse):-
    list_length(ListOfResponse, NumOfResponse),
    NumOfResponse == 0,
    write('I''M NOT SURE IF I  UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU  ARE TALKING ABOUT.'), !.

no_response_found(_).

get_keyword(KeyList, [KeyList,_]).
get_response(RespList, [_, RespList]).

select_response(RespList, Response):-
    list_length(RespList, NumOfResponse),
    IndexOfResponse is integer(random(NumOfResponse)),
    select(IndexOfResponse, RespList, Response), !.

select_response(_, _).

find_match(Input, [FirstRecord|RestDatabase], ListOfResponse):-
    get_keyword(Keyword, FirstRecord),
    Keyword == Input, get_response(ListOfResponse, FirstRecord), !;
    find_match(Input, RestDatabase, ListOfResponse).

find_match(_, [_], _).

chatterbot2:- 
    repeat,
    nl, write('>'),
    read(Input),
    knowledge_base(ListOfRecord),
    find_match(Input, ListOfRecord, ListOfResponse),
    no_response_found(ListOfResponse),
    select_response(ListOfResponse, Response),
    write(Response), nl,
    quit_session(Input).
```

When I try to use it I get:

```
鐀1 ?- chatterbot2.

>hi.
I'M NOT SURE IF I  UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU  ARE TALKING ABOUT.
ERROR: random/1: Domain error: `not_less_than_one' expected, found `0'
   Exception: (7) select_response([], _G492) ? creep
2 ?- chatterbot2.

>'What do you do ?'.
I'M NOT SURE IF I  UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU  ARE TALKING ABOUT.
ERROR: random/1: Domain error: `not_less_than_one' expected, found `0'
   Exception: (7) select_response([], _G485) ? creep
3 ?- chatterbot2.

>'Dog is black'.
I'M NOT SURE IF I  UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU  ARE TALKING ABOUT.
ERROR: random/1: Domain error: `not_less_than_one' expected, found `0'
   Exception: (7) select_response([], _G485) ? creep
4 ?-
```

EDIT:
With random value =/= 0 :

```
1 ?- chatterbot2.

>'NOT IN BASE'.
I'M NOT SURE WHAT ARE YOU TALKING ABOUT._G907
```

is it possible to delete that value of blank arguement **_G907** ?> and become only sentence?

Comment: Just to clarify, if you're converting to SWI prolog, make that clear in the question and add a tag for it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your errors in this particular example are caused by your input. Your input is matched to the first entries in your knowledge_base. Since none of your inputs match, the list that is returned has length 0, causing a problem with the call to random, which seems to need a value of at least 1.

Try 'WHAT IS YOUR NAME' as input for example and see if that works.

Comment: 1 ?- chatterbot2.

>'WHAT IS YOUR NAME'.
YOU CAN CALL ME CHATTERBOT2.

so it works, hmm is it possible to generate random answer without that things: ERROR: random/1: Domain error: `not_less_than_one' expected, found `0'
   Exception: (7) select_response([], _G485) ? creep

Comment: If you get that error, it means that at some point the random has gotten a value of 0 as input. So check why that happens and try to avoid it. Anyway, in this case it's more a limitation of the example. You can only input entries that are explicitly defined in your knowledge_base. If you don't, you'll get the error.

Comment: When changed to another value as for eg. 666 -> ERROR dissapears, but there is still one bad thing - take a look:

>'Dog is black'.
I'M NOT SURE IF I  UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU  ARE TALKING ABOUT._G421



Questions from knowledge_base works as they should.

Comment: Yes I have to improve that base to be better, but first that things;) -> then I'll try to do that bot by myself , but for that i need to understand this one and its 'weak' points